Reinitialize ajax result when clicking addRow
I need help with fixing the javascript for my project please.
I have a dropdown list of Student, where whenever the selected Student is changing, there's an ajax script to get the list of Activities available for that particular Student. The script is working fine.
My problem is when I'd like to combine with adding/deleting rows into table dynamically : whenever I clicked addRow, the list of Activities can't be modified, and it's copying the row above.
Here's the blade
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="student_id">{{ trans('cruds.clubRegistration.fields.student') }}</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="student_id" id="student_id">
        @foreach($students as $id => $entry)
            <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('student_id') == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $entry }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<table class="table w-full" id="products_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                {{ trans('cruds.clubRegistrationDetail.fields.club_activity') }}
            </th>
            <th>
                {{ trans('cruds.clubRegistrationDetail.fields.schedules') }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="product0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control select2 " name="club_activity[]" id="club_activity_id">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control select2 " name="schedules[]" id="schedules" multiple>

                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="product1"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">+ Add Row</button>
        <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">- Delete Row</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    let row_number = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let new_row_number = row_number - 1;
        $('#product' + row_number).html($('#product' + new_row_number).html()).find('td:first-child');
        $('#products_table').append(
                '<tr id="product' + (row_number + 1) +
                '"></tr>'
            );
        row_number++;

    });

    $("#delete_row").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(row_number > 1){
            $("#product" + (row_number - 1)).html('');
            row_number--;
        }
    });

</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#student_id').on('change', function(){
            var studentID = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/getClubsbyStudentGrade/" + studentID,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(dataD){
                    var options = "<option>---  Select the activities ---</option>";
                    $.each(dataD, function (key,value){
                        options += '<option value="'+ key +'">' + value + '</option>';
                    });
                    $("#club_activity_id").html(options);
                },
                error:function(err){
                    alert("Student is not enrolled in current school year");
                }
            });
        });
        $('#club_activity_id').on('change', function(){
            var selD = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/getClubSchedules/" + selD,
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    var options = "<option>---  Select the schedules ---</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (key, value){
                        options += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#schedules").html(options);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>

Can anyone please help me?
Many thanks in advance

What do you mean by: the list of Activities can't be modified, and it's copying the row above? please elaborate

Let's say for the the first row of available Activities, I've selected an option, then whenever i clicked on addRow, the copied rows will copy the values of the first row, and I cannot edit them.

Kindly create a minimal reproducible example
